# convert/rename keys in object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object looking like:

```
const test = {
  picture_905_position: 'right',
  picture_626_position: 'right',
  picture_953_position: 'left'
}
```

I would like to rename all keys to be

```
const test = {
  metric[picture_905_position]: 'right',
  metric[picture_626_position]: 'right',
  metric[picture_953_position]: 'left'
}
```

I've come up with this so far, which fails, likely because it's not valid :)
So how do i rename the key and assign the correct value?

```
const test = {
  picture_905_position: 'right',
  picture_626_position: 'right',
  picture_953_position: 'left'
}
const metrics = [];

let newTest = Object.keys(test).map(key => {
    return 'metric['+key+']' = test[key]
});

console.log(newTest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to create a new object (not an array which is what you were trying to do).

```js
const test = {
  picture_905_position: 'right',
  picture_626_position: 'right',
  picture_953_position: 'left'
}

let newTest = Object.entries(test).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    return { ...acc, [`metric[${key}]`]: value };
}, {});

console.log(newTest)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use map here because the map will return an array of something(what you're returning) and you want the result in an object.

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get the desired result.

```js
const test = {
  picture_905_position: "right",
  picture_626_position: "right",
  picture_953_position: "left",
};

const result = Object.keys(test).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[`metric[${curr}]`] = test[curr];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track when you iterate through the object keys. But `.map()` returns an array.
You can use `forEach()` to perform an action based on each

```
const test = {
  picture_905_position: 'right',
  picture_626_position: 'right',
  picture_953_position: 'left'
}
const ans = {};

Object.keys(test).forEach(key => {
     ans['metric['+key+']'] = test[key]
});
```

Note: This does not modify the original object. You can also do that using the same object instead of `ans` and `delete` operator.

Comment: Sure consider upvoting if this helped you.